# If I install Laravel using homestead via virtualbox, will that affect my existing MAMP Installation

Tags: macos, laravel, mamp, homestead

I Currently have projects I'm working on using MAMP. But, I wanted to try out laravel, and I did so by installing virtual box, and then installing homestead through the virtual box. I have projects I am currently working on in MAMP, so my concern is will I be able to run homestead and MAMP simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

> ...will that affect my existing MAMP Installation?

No it won't. That is one the main points (having an independent from your local machine's environment) of using a vm (homestead).

> ...will I be able to run homestead and MAMP simultaneously

Yes, you can run them simultaneously.